# DateTime being persisted to one DB column but not the other in Symfony 4.4 app

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have a baffling issues where I have a `DateTime` object which seems to be able to be persisted and flushed to one column, but **not the other**.

I have checked the DB, the data isn't be written to the "protectiondate" column.

```
$lifecycle->setRemovalDate($extendedProtectionDate); // this line works
$lifecycle->setProtectionDate($extendedProtectionDate); // this line doesn't
$em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
$em->persist($lifecycle);
$em->flush();
```

The fields are defined identically:

```
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="removalDate", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $removalDate;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="protectionDate", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $protectionDate;
```

As are the accessors and mutators:

```
   /**
     * @param DateTime|null $removalDate
     *
     * @return Lifecycle
     */
    public function setRemovalDate($removalDate = null) : self
    {
        $this->removalDate = $removalDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTime|null
     */
    public function getRemovalDate() : ?DateTime
    {
        return $this->removalDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTime|null $protectionDate
     *
     * @return Lifecycle
     */
    public function setProtectionDate($protectionDate = null) : self
    {
        $this->protectionDate = $protectionDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTime|null
     */
    public function getProtectionDate() : ?DateTime
    {
        return $this->protectionDate;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure, database scheme is in sync, caches are cleared and you're really setting the same date (and/or NULL) while trying it out? sorry for the obvious ones, but it's really baffling.

Comment: Yes, I haven't made any recent changes to that table and I can see the "removalDate" column getting updated with the same value. I can set the "protectionDate" field to `NULL`, but not any `DateTime` value.

Comment: are there any lifecycle events, event subscripers etc. which could change your data pre flush? what's the actual error message you're getting?

Comment: @LBA No, I have no lifecycle events or even susbcriptions. No pre-flush hacks either, the entity is bog standard. This is a real head scratcher. I'm not getting any error whatsoever, it just doesn't persist the object or flush to the database.

Comment: which sql statements do you see in symfony's debugger view or the doctrine log?

Comment: and when calling $em->persist your $lifecycle has both dates correctly set in the object already?

Comment: shouldn´t `type="date"` be `type="datetime"` ?